# How can I record audio in & mic in as 1 channel in Audacity?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity, audio-recording

I am trying to record my podcast, which I do using Google Hangouts & Audacity.

I recently switched from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu. In Windows I was using the software [Virtual Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/VirtualCables.htm) + [VoiceMeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm) to mix my microphone in & audio in from Google Hangouts into a single channel on the virtual cable which I would then record in Audacity.

This worked great, but I cannot find any sort of similar setup for Ubuntu. I'm sure I'm either overlooking something and/or still don't quite understand ALSA/Pulse Audio.

Comment: Can you still record both the input in two channel? if so, record them in two mono channel and then simply combine them in one stereo channel before export.

Answer (score 2):

It will be difficult with pulse or alsa (directly).

But you can use jack audio server (version 2 is better).
With jack you can route audio signals from sources (line in, mic, etc.) to sinks (speakers, recorders, streaming encoders), passing through filters (vu meters, equalizers, etc), using a sort of virtual cable.

Virtual audio cables on Windows got the idea from JACK :D

The tricky part is that you have to configure jack on your main sound card and hope the sound card allows you to use mic AND line-in at the same time (it's a hardware feature).